# Windows Server Datacenter Edition - Unlimited Virtual Machines

Tags: hyper-v, guest, windows-server-2019

Need some clarification on the following.

Datacenter Edition description lists:

> **Can be used as virtualization guest**: Yes, unlimited virtual machines,
>   plus one Hyper-V host per license

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/editions-comparison-19

The way I understand it is, that I can create unlimited guest virtual machines without additional keys.

Is my understanding correct?

If not, please explain.

If yes, how do I go about creating guest virtual machines from the host's license?

This is not a general licensing question, more specifically regarding guest OS activation.

Comment: Note that we can answer technical questions about provisioning your VMs, but we don't handle [questions about licensing itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue).

Comment: Don’t forget detail like all cpu core must be licensed and all hist must be (if more than one host in example)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Windows VMs running on Datacenter are licensed through [Automatic Virtual Machine Activation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/vm-activation-19), which lets a VM activate via the Hyper-V service on the host.

All you need to do is to provision the VM with the appropriate AVMA product key, which are provided in [Microsoft's documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/vm-activation-19#avma-keys).